# Array manipulation with nested arrays

Tags: arrays, nested

let names = ['Ayomide',['Tolu',['Tola',['Chuka',['Dan']]]]];
How can I manipulate each element in this nested array. It's all index 0 and 1. Trying to figure out how to loop through this to get the elements individually, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use `name.flat(Infinity)` to flatten it to a single array (Infinity tells it to go as deep as necessary), and then you can just use `.forEach` or whatever

```js
let names = ['Ayomide',['Tolu',['Tola',['Chuka',['Dan']]]]];
console.log(names.flat(Infinity))
```

Comment: That method is lit. Thanks a lot